# Couldn't see the tab I created when I log in as another user (on Force.com Platform)

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I was working one of the force.com coockbooks. I created a Mileage object and addes some features like workflows and etc (This is done after I log on as an admin in my developer force account). I then created another user(Standard user). And I wanted that user to use the Mileage object to create new Mileage. However, Mileage tab is not visible. I tried by making it visible to all users in Create Apps. But, still it is not visible (as a tab) to my new created user.

How should I make Mileage tab visible so that the new created user can use Mileage tab to create a new record?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure a non admin user has rights to access the object-tab you're creating, you should:

- Verify that the user's profile, as a minimum, has read access to the object (go to user's profile's setup screen and verify the "Custom Object Permissions" section)
- Ensure that the object you're displaying in the tab is "deployed" (This is a simple property on your custom object definition called "Deployment Status")

In addition to these suggestions, it could be that the tab is hidden to the user. This could be taken care of as described in Ralph's answer.

Comment: Found the answer on another thread. Out of the box profiles such as standard user can't be changed. You have to clone the profile and then make changes to give permission to custom objects.

Comment: Thanks for reminder about changing object to "deployed". I was really worried I had misunderstood permission sets and apps until I realized the objects were still "in developent"!

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you'll want to check

First, make sure the tab is visible to the profile you're logged in as.  From [documentation](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_tab_visibility.htm) (login may be required):

1. Click Your Name | Setup | Manage Users | Profiles.
2. Select a profile.
3. Depending on which user interface you're using, do one of the following:

   a. Enhanced profile user interface—In the Find Settings... box, enter the name of the tab you want and select it from the list, then click Edit.

   b. Original profile user interface—Click Edit, then scroll to the Tab Settings section.
   Specify the tab visibility.
4. (Original profile user interface only) To reset users’ tab customizations to the tab visibility settings that you specify, select Overwrite users' personal tab customizations.
5. Click Save.

This may take care of it.  If the tab still isn't visible when you're logged in as the new user, click the '+' at just after the last tab and then click 'customize tabs'.  Select the new mileage tab and add it to your app.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems the right way to display the tab. But, still I couldn't see the tab in the specified user. Any ways, I may look at it in detail and if it is not working I will create the Mileage app again which will not take more than half an hour. I appreciate your help